# data.table works in console but fails with R CMD INSTALL

Tags: r, package, data.table

Minimal example: I have an R package whose sole .R file contains the code

```
data.table::data.table(iris)[Species == "setosa"]
```

Expected output:

```
    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
 1:          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
 2:          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
 ...
```

This runs fine interactively (and when compiling with [knitr](http://yihui.name/knitr/), and with `r --vanilla`).

**However, when I run `R CMD INSTALL` on the package, it fails with:**

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(x, i, j) : object 'Species' not found
```

Why would this happen only with R CMD INSTALL, and how can I avoid it?

***Details:***

**Package Imports**

The package DESCRIPTION file includes the line

```
Imports: data.table
```

**Transcript of failed R CMD INSTALL**

```
Rcmd.exe INSTALL --no-multiarch --with-keep.source MYPKG

* installing to library 'C:/Users/.../Documents/R/win-library/3.2'
* installing *source* package 'MYPKG' ...
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
Error in `[.data.frame`(x, i) : object 'Species' not found
Error : unable to load R code in package 'MYPKG'
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'MYPKG'
* removing 'C:/Users/.../Documents/R/win-library/3.2/MYPKG'
* restoring previous 'C:/Users/.../Documents/R/win-library/3.2/MYPKG'

Exited with status 1.
```

**Version information**

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 8.1 x64 (build 9600)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Norwegian (Bokmål)_Norway.1252
[2] LC_CTYPE=Norwegian (Bokmål)_Norway.1252
[3] LC_MONETARY=Norwegian (Bokmål)_Norway.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C
[5] LC_TIME=Norwegian (Bokmål)_Norway.1252

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] data.table_1.9.7 chron_2.3-47
```

Comment: Can you check if `data.table(iris)[Species == "setosa"]` will work instead?

Comment: Did you import `filter` and `data.table` in `NAMESPACE` file?

Comment: @jangorecki: `data.table(iris)[Species == "setosa"]` behaves the same: works in console, but fails with R CMD INSTALL. That removes dplyr from the equation, thanks. I'll update my question accordingly. 

As for my NAMESPACE file, it is empty save for `exportPattern("^[[:alpha:]]+")`.

Comment: so this is potentially the reason, in NAMESPACE you need to import too, not just export.

Comment: @jangorecki: Adding `import(data.table)` to NAMESPACE did the trick (i.e. I can successfully R CMD INSTALL via Control-Shift-B in RStudio). Please add your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always need to maintain `NAMESPACE` file, not just `DESCRIPTION`.
`import(data.table)` to NAMESPACE fill will solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks. I was expecting RStudio to [build the NAMESPACE file for me](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/namespace.html#NAMESPACE) if I added the magical comment `#' @import data.table`. I didn't realize 1) that I [needed to specifically enable this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35465179/roxygen2-and-controlling-namespace-generation-in-2-related-packages) in `RStudio > Build > Configure Build Tools > Generate documentation with Roxygen > Configure` and 2) evidently, the magical comment must be prepended to a *function*, not a plain expression such as `data.table(iris)[Species == "setosa"]`.